# Travelling with EU with a receipt of carte de sejour

Tags: international-travel, eu, study

I have an indian passport and have been studying in France for 1 year. I have applied for my carte de sejour for the first time. I want to visite Germany and come back, can I do this on my receipt of application with an expired visa? I wish to take a flight.

Comment: Technically, no, it is not allowed or encouraged by the French authorities. As to what might happen in practice, I don't know.

Comment: Within the Schengen area there are no systematic immigration checks. So it is very well possible nobody will ask to see anything. 
However I would wait with travelling until you actually have your residence permit in hand.